# SQLselect and pivot depending on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

I have two tables table1 with col1 & table2 with col2 and col3
I'm trying the following code to select them:

```
select col1,col2,col3
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
```

it gives me the result as shown:
[selected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKpPf.png)

I want to get this result:

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojeUL.png)

how could I do this?
thanks in advance...

Comment: I might even recommend against this query/design.  As the number of `Col2` values increases, so will the number of columns in your result set. You'd probably want to use dynamic SQL here for a robust answer.

Comment: How many values can be in the "Others" column?

Comment: my values are not fixed number, the number of values changed. my all values are varchar values and I have no integers in it. I will give an extra explanation: when col1 value = a   ,I want to select values from col2 as one row where col3 value = x and concat the other values which are not 'x'  as one column called others, and I want to run the same query again but now when the col3 = y , so now the one row values will be now when the col3 =y and any values which are not 'y' will go to others now, and so on.

Comment: I think dynamic is the best way to do that, but I do not know how to do it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Taymourlank, try to run select from my answer. Is the result is what you need? And you can change condition `col3 = 'X'` to `col3 = 'Y'` and so on to get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only a finite number of values in columns "T1"..."T5" and "Others" (for example, no more than 5), then your select could look like

```
select col1, x2.*
from table1
cross apply (
  select [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],
         concat([6], ', '+[7], ', '+[8], ', '+[9], ', '+[10]) Others
  from (
    select col2, rs + row_number()over(partition by rs order by col2) rn
    from table2
      cross apply (select case when col3 = 'X' then 0 else 5 end rs)x1
    where table2.table1_id = table1.id
  )a pivot (max(col2) for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]))p
)x2
```

[See demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d85f/1)

Otherwise you probably need a dynamic sql, as Tim suggested.

Comment: thank you very much, it is a perfect answer for me that solve my problem. but there is still one thing that how could I make it dynamic when I do not know the number of values.

Comment: @Taymourlank, dynamic sql means that you develop not select expression, but rather code, that builds appropriate select every time it need to be executed. It's hard to give an exact solution, 'cos it depends on details of your project: what is a client, how it requests, process and displays data, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use "case when" and "group by" like

```
 select col1,sum(case when col2=value1 then vluee1 end) as T1,
 sum(case when cols2=value3 then value3 end) as T2
 from table1
 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
 group by col1
```